# PrimeNG AutoComplete: Re-run search after selecting specific entry

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

After selecting a specific entry from the autocomplete results, I want to re-run the search.

PrimeNg v7.1.3

I've tried using view child and then calling the show method for the autocomplete, but that doesn't seem to help.

You can review an example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-b6ffq3

After selecting the specific entry, I'd expect the results to appear, but they don't.

Comment: the search does "re-run" but it looks like the select options don't show unless you start to type in the field again.

Comment: Looks like the search method from the prime ng component is available but I've also tried that and it doesn't seem to make a difference. So there's no way to programmatically run the search again?

Comment: I took a different route and instead of including the option as part of the search results, I appended an option outside of them. Then I was able to stop propagation and re-run search.